# Java support for WS-Fed vs SAML as a sign in protocol

Tags: java, .net, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I'm configuring ADFS for a .NET based application and I'm trying to decide whether to use WS-Fed or SAML as a sign-in protocol. Both meet my requirements.

I plan to offer SSO with a Java based application in a few months. My research leads me to believe there is more support for SAML in the Java community... but I'm not a Java developer.

Is there a well known Java authentication package to handle authentication I can refer to? (e.g. nuget or library package in the .NET world).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [I need a SAML stack — now!](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

WS-Fed is more Microsoft based which is why there are more SAML options in the open source / Java world.